# How to replace the default motd for AWS Linux 2023

Tags: ssh, amazon-linux-2023

How do I replace the default motd (message-of-the-day) for AWS Linux 2023?

I modified **/etc/motd** with a new message, but the default text-characters-bird thingy still shows when I login with SSH.

Answer (score 1):

Evidently, in this flavor of Linux (AWS Linux 2023), the motd comes from **/etc/motd** **AND** whatever files are in the **/usr/lib/motd.d** directory.  The default is **/usr/lib/motd.d/30-banner**.  You can delete that file and only the **/etc/motd** contents will be displayed when logging in.

For safety I created a **/usr/lib/motd.d/save** directory and moved **30-banner** to that save directory.  Never know if I may want it back, like if I use this instance to launch another.